# Ansible filter item in list using variables+wildcard

Tags: list, ansible

1. I have the below lists stored in variable `results_one.msg`

```json
[
  {
   "IP": [
      "192.168.1.100",
      "192.168.1.101"
    ],
   "Pool": "lan_pool_sftp",
   "Members": [
      "sftpnode01:5425",
      "sftpnode02:5425"
    ]
  },
{
   "IP": [
     "192.168.1.103",
     "192.168.1.104"
    ],
   "Pool": "icmp-net-pool",
   "Members": [
      "icmpnet01:8443",
      "icmpnet02:8443"
    ]
  }
]
```

2. I have another variable `node_name`

I would like to get the `Pool` and `Members` information from above output, by querying one of the members name.

For example, if I assign the variable `node_name: icmpnet02`
I want to get the output stored as in respective variable names as below.

```yaml
pool_name: icmp-net-pool
pool_members: [ icmpnet01:8443,icmpnet02:8443 ]
```

I tried as below and I'm unable to get it

```yaml
- set_fact: 
    pool_name: "{{ item.Pool }}"
    pool_members: "{{ item.Members }}"
  with_items: "{{results_one.msg }}"
  when: 'item.Members.0 is defined and "node_name:*" in item.Members'
```

Comment: apologies, noted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a list of lists of members with their names only:

```yaml
    _members_hostnames: "{{ results_one.msg | map(attribute='Members') 
      | map('map', 'regex_replace', '^(.*):.*$', '\\1') }}"
```

Gives:

```json
    "_members_hostnames": [
        [
            "sftpnode01",
            "sftpnode02"
        ],
        [
            "icmpnet01",
            "icmpnet02"
        ]
    ]
```

2. select the matching entry from your relevant variable, i.e.

   - create a list of tuples associating each original element with its counterpart calculated members hostnames
   - retain only element where hostname is present in the list
   - keep only the first element of tupple (i.e. the orginal entry)
   - keep only the first element from list

```yaml
    _matching_entry: "{{ results_one.msg | zip(_members_hostnames) 
      | selectattr(1, 'contains', node_name) | map(attribute=0) | first }}"
```

gives

```json
    "_matching_entry": {
        "IP": [
            "192.168.1.103",
            "192.168.1.104"
        ],
        "Members": [
            "icmpnet01:8443",
            "icmpnet02:8443"
        ],
        "Pool": "icmp-net-pool"
    }
```

3. use the matching entry to extract whatever variable you need:

```yaml
    pool_name: "{{ _matching_entry.Pool }}"
    pool_members: "{{ _matching_entry.Members }}"
```

---

Putting it all together in a test playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # Your orig data on a single line for legibility
    results_one: {"msg":[{"IP":["192.168.1.100","192.168.1.101"],"Pool":"lan_pool_sftp","Members":["sftpnode01:5425","sftpnode02:5425"]},{"IP":["192.168.1.103","192.168.1.104"],"Pool":"icmp-net-pool","Members":["icmpnet01:8443","icmpnet02:8443"]}]}

    node_name: icmpnet02

    _members_hostnames: "{{ results_one.msg | map(attribute='Members') 
      | map('map', 'regex_replace', '^(.*):.*$', '\\1') }}"

    _matching_entry: "{{ results_one.msg | zip(_members_hostnames) 
      | selectattr(1, 'contains', node_name) | map(attribute=0) | first }}"

    pool_name: "{{ _matching_entry.Pool }}"
    pool_members: "{{ _matching_entry.Members }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg:
          - Pool name is {{ pool_name }}
          - Pool members are {{ pool_members }}
```

Which gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "Pool name is icmp-net-pool",
        "Pool members are ['icmpnet01:8443', 'icmpnet02:8443']"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: '_members_hostnames: "{{ results_one.msg | map(attribute='Members') | map('map', 'regex_replace', '^(.*):.*$', '\\1') }}"'

returns 
`
_members_names": "[<generator object do_map at 0x7f5e2ab21dc0>`


But,
`_members_hostnames: "{{ results_one.msg | map(attribute='Members') | list }}" `

returns



 `"_members_hostnames": [
        [
            "sftpnode01:5425",
            "sftpnode02:5425"
        ],
        [
            "icmpnet01:8443",
            "icmpnet02:8443"
        ]
    ]`

Comment: 1) please don't paste large portion of code into comments. Edit your question instead. 2) please dont use an outdated and unmaintained version of ansible. The above error and the workaround you used (actually mandatory with your version) with the `list` filter is because you are using ansible < 2.10. Upgrade.